# Jquery Coin Slider - not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to integrate [Coin Slider](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/) into my page, and I've downloaded and attached the latest Jquery to my header, along with all of the necessary Coin-slider files. However, the page simply stacks the images as if I had simply inserted  tags.

The paths for all of the files are correct. I tried following his instructions to the letter on the "how to install" page, with no success. It won't work in IE8, or the latest versions of Chrome or Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/paradigm.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Paradigm Solutions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <div id="leftMenu"></div>
    <div id="coin-slider">
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/products/ie/home/" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.vexite.com/images/2011/06/browser-war-illustration.jpg" alt="IESucks" />
                <span>
                    <b>Don't Use IE</b><br />
                    Internet Explorer is an inferior product that should be destroyed.
                </span>
            </a>

        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/products/ie/home/" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.vexite.com/images/2011/06/browser-war-illustration.jpg" alt="IESucks" />
                <span>
                    <b>Don't Use IE</b><br />
                    Internet Explorer is an inferior product that should be destroyed.
                </span>
            </a>
    </div>


    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coin-slider').coinslider();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your script tags from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
```

coin-slider depends on jQuery therefore it must be loaded before.... And I would suggest you remove `js/coin-slider.js` as `js/coin-slider.min.js` and `js/coin-slider.js` are the same thing ... the `.min` is just a minified version of the other

Comment: Curses. Beaten by 43 seconds. +1 :)

Comment: OMG.. What a simple over sight on my part. Wow. I feel like an idiot. 

You are a true hero of the three kingdoms, sir.

Comment: @SiriusMane we have all been there ... I bet you don't make that error again ;-)

Comment: Absolutely I won't. I want to slap myself across the face.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your javascript file includes is very important. jQuery should always be first (as is evident in the production documentation). Also, you don't need BOTH coin-slider includes. The .min will be enough:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js">
```

Answer (score 1):

This one may sound obvious but the coin-slider package doesn't always come packaged with jQuery, so make sure you have jQuery in your javascript folder before linking too it  c(:

Answer (score 0):

it works well

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

[check this link for code](http://www.4shared.com/zip/1AK-AybV/coin-slider.html)